# React tutorial tic tac toe will not pass value to my handleClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to go through the react tutorial here:  https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe

I am early on when it just is trying to pass a value to the `handleClick` function for which square to set to 'X'.

For some reason, the `onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)}` syntax (or whichever square value is passed for a given square) does not get passed into `handleClick`.  I can breakpoint in the function in the browser and clicking in a square gets to the handler, but the parameter value is undefined according to the browser dev tools, and so I never succeed in setting a square to X.  For curiosity I tried adding a specific `handleClick0` function that doesn't take a parameter and always sets X in box 0, and that works fine.  My complete code is below.  I am pretty sure it matches the tutorial at that step of the tutorial, but I cannot understand what I have wrong that the value is never passed into the handler.  I also get that later in the tutorial the code gets improved in many ways, but at this early point I thought it should work as copied in from that step of the tutorial, but in the handler the browser says i is undefined when I hit the breakpoint there after clicking on any of squares 1 through 8. I don't know if this matters but I am using Chrome.

```
import React  from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

function Square({ value, onSquareClick }) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={onSquareClick} >
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}

export default function Board() {
  const [squares, setSquares] = useState(Array(9).fill(null));
   function handleClick({i}) {
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    nextSquares[{i}] = "X";
    setSquares(nextSquares);
}

function handleClick0() {
  const nextSquares = squares.slice();
  nextSquares[0] = "X";
  setSquares(nextSquares);
}

return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[0]} onSquareClick={handleClick0} /> 
        <Square value={squares[1]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(1)} />
        <Square value={squares[2]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(2)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[3]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(3)} />
        <Square value={squares[4]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(4)} />
        <Square value={squares[5]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(5)} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={squares[6]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(6)} />
        <Square value={squares[7]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(7)} />
        <Square value={squares[8]} onSquareClick={() => handleClick(8)} />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I was expecting that I would have a value that was passed in in the `handleClick` function.

Comment: You are passing an object `{i}` as index every time `handleClick()` is run. You need to pass the index itself: `nextSquares[i] = "X";`. Same goes for the argument in `handleClick` function. You need to change the signature to: `function handleClick(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleClick` function, you have `{i}` in a few places where it should just be `i`. You use the `{i}` syntax within a JSX block to get the variable's value, but inside a function like `handleClick` you can just use `i` directly:

```
function handleClick({i}) {  // extra { } around the i
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    nextSquares[{i}] = "X";  // extra { } around the i
    setSquares(nextSquares);
}
```

So you want this instead:

```
function handleClick(i) {
    const nextSquares = squares.slice();
    nextSquares[i] = "X";
    setSquares(nextSquares);
}
```

Comment: Thanks  for the answer, looks like we commented at almost the same time.  I feel dumb because I have many years programming experience, but not in almost a devade and not in these languages.

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  I am still learning the syntax and I should not have had the function declared as

```
function handleClick({i})
```

with the curly braces in there.  It should have been:

```
function handleClick(i)
```